# CSS missing for some components on Vite bundle

Tags: reactjs, bundler, vite

The title really says it all, some components have their CSS included correctly and others are missing the CSS altogether. There is no difference between the working and non-working components that I can find, but each time I run the build script, the same components are missing the CSS. The CSS files are being imported normally -

```
import "./WeeklyTrend.css"
```

I'm using **Vite** as my bundler, I have not made any changes to the config beyond what comes with the react template, which I will include below.

```
import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react'

export default defineConfig({
   plugins: [react()],
   base: "https://www.--fakeserverurl--.com/"
})
```

The css in question is missing altogether from the bundled CSS file. I'm probably missing something simple, but I really have looked all over the place with no success. Thanks in advance.